# Background deletion and UITableView scrolling deleted row

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, background

I have a background ping to a server that pulls some xml and updates my context. In the frontend I can edit managed object as well. I stress tested it and works fine with no deadlock etc.

When I delete a row in the background fetch from server, it happens that the `UITableView` crashes when I scroll to this data. The array used for this table is not empty but somehow null in the deleted rows.

Is there any specific approach when deleting rows using Core Data? It is only a problem the split second from the deletion to the save operation - if the user scrolls the tableview in where the deleted row is present.

Comment: Have you implemented NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

Comment: Provide more details. Thanks.

Comment: I kind of solved it by using a plain notifier to update the tableview. The problem was when rows in or outside the tableview where deleted and scrolling began. It could be that my didChangeObject core data thing didn't work? Maybe because I update in the background from a non-method...(?) I tried out the NSFecthedResultController and works nicely, but I can just not exactly see the big benefit ? You still have to observe for changes when updating content like before...(?)